# Submit Form to Call API Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a form in Next.js. I also built an api route in the `/api` folder. How can I make it so that when I submit the form, the data gets sent to my api? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your initial code for the form and api?

Comment: @PeterPark I wish I had some initial code, but don't know where to start... thanks for the response!!

Comment: It is better to share the handler function of form submit and the form components.